# VBA - Function that returns an array with each element being a range

Tags: arrays, vba, range

EDIT: You can find the revised code under 'Corrected Code' below

I'm struggling to work out how to write a VBA function that will return an array, where each element of the array is a range object. Ideally, I would like to know how to write so that each range object can be a dis-contiguous selection of cells, in pseudo code, that would be something like:

MyReturnedArrayOfRangeObjects (1) = (A1:C3, A6, B4:B6)

I found this thread:
[Using an Array of Ranges in VBA - Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630704/using-an-array-of-ranges-in-vba-excel)
This gets me a close, but I must be doing something wrong in my function declaration (I think).

A bunch of the original code was irrelevant to the question, so it's been removed and I've made a simple example that would return just a single cell in each array element. When I run this, the code below returns a ByRef type mismatch on the line:

`Set FindLastContentCell(i) = LastCell`

Apart from the code below, I have tried making the function declaration a variant (no change). If I remove 'Set' from the line of code shown above, I get a 'Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object':

```
    Function FindLastContentCell(Optional WB As Workbook = Nothing, Optional JustWS As Worksheet = Nothing) As Range()

    Dim myLastRow As Long, myLastCol As Long, i As Long
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim dummyRng As Range, LastCell As Range
    Dim AnyMerged As Variant
    Dim Proceed As Boolean
    Dim iResponse As Integer

    ' Initialise variables
    Set LastCell = Nothing
    i = 0

    [Bunch of extra code removed]

    If JustWS Is Nothing Then
        If WB Is Nothing Then Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
        For Each wks In WB.Worksheets

            [Bunch of extra code removed]

            If Proceed Then
                With wks
                    myLastRow = 0
                    myLastCol = 0
                    Set dummyRng = .UsedRange
                    On Error Resume Next
                    myLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", after:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                searchdirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).row
                    myLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", after:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                searchdirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
                End With
                On Error GoTo 0
                Set LastCell = Cells(myLastRow, myLastCol)
                ReDim Preserve FindLastContentCell(0 To i)
                Set FindLastContentCell(i) = LastCell
                i = i + 1        
            End If
        Next wks
    End If

End Function
```

The calling sub is:

```
Sub temp()

Call FindLastContentCell

End Sub
```

---

Corrected Code

---

```
Sub Temp()

Dim rng As Range, results() As Range
Dim x As Variant

results() = FindLastContentCell

End Sub

Function FindLastContentCell(Optional WB As Workbook = Nothing, Optional JustWS As Worksheet = Nothing) As Variant

    'Modded by me

    'From:
    ' http://www.contextures.com/xlfaqApp.html#Unused

    Dim myLastRow As Long, myLastCol As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim dummyRng As Range, LastCell As Range, LastCells() As Range
    Dim AnyMerged As Variant
    Dim Proceed As Boolean
    Dim iResponse As Integer

    ' Initialise variables
    Set LastCell = Nothing
    i = 0

    ' If the code is only to consider one worksheet passed as JustWS
    ' then determine if something was passed as JustWS
    If JustWS Is Nothing Then
        ' Nothing is found in JustWS, so code runs for each worksheet, either in the passed workbook
        ' object, or else for the ActiveWorkbook
        If WB Is Nothing Then Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
        For Each wks In WB.Worksheets
    ' This is where the code will run from if something was passed as JustWS, otherwise the line below
    ' has no impact on code execution
RunOnce:
            ' Check for merged cells
            AnyMerged = wks.UsedRange.MergeCells
            ' Responde accordingly and let user decide if neccessary
            If AnyMerged = False Then
                Proceed = True
            ElseIf AnyMerged = True Then
                MsgBox "The whole used range is merged. Nothing will be done on this worksheet"
                Proceed = False
            ElseIf IsNull(AnyMerged) Then
                iResponse = MsgBox("There are some merged cells on the worksheet." & vbNewLine & _
                                "This might cause a problem with the calculation of the last cells location." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                                "Do you want to proceed anyway?", _
                                vbYesNo, _
                                "Calculate Last Cell")
                If iResponse = vbYes Then
                    Proceed = True
                Else
                    Proceed = False
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "If you this, an error has occured in FindLastContentCell." & vbNewLine & _
                        "Code execution has been stopped."
                Stop
            End If

            If Proceed Then
                With wks
                    myLastRow = 0
                    myLastCol = 0
                    Set dummyRng = .UsedRange
                    On Error Resume Next
                    myLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", after:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                searchdirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).row
                    myLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", after:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                searchdirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
                End With
                On Error GoTo 0
                Set LastCell = Cells(myLastRow, myLastCol)

                ReDim Preserve LastCells(i)
                Set LastCells(i) = LastCell
                i = i + 1

                ' * This is where code will exit if only a single worksheet is passed.
                ' * Exits if a worksheet object was passed as JustWS, rather than looping through each worksheet
                ' in the workbook variable that was either passed, or which defaults to ActiveWorkbook
                If Not JustWS Is Nothing Then
                    FindLastContentCell = LastCells
                    Exit Function
                End If

            End If
        Next wks
    ' If a worksheet was passed as JustWS
    Else
        GoTo RunJustOneWS
    End If

    FindLastContentCell = LastCells

    ' Exit upon completion of a workbook variable any code
    ' below here is only run if a worksheet is passed as JustWS
    Exit Function

    ' Setup to run the single worksheet that was passed as JustWS
RunJustOneWS:
        Set wks = JustWS
        GoTo RunOnce

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you say, it seems like you don't have too clear ideas regarding `Arrays` and `Ranges` in VBA. Here you have a sample code clarifying both issues a bit:

```
Function getRandomRanges() As Range()

    Dim totRanges As Integer: totRanges = 3
    ReDim outRanges(totRanges - 1) As Range

    Set outRanges(0) = Range("A1")
    Set outRanges(1) = Range("B2:C10")
    Set outRanges(2) = Cells(2, 3)

    getRandomRanges = outRanges

End Function
```

You can call this function by doing:

```
Dim retrievedRanges() As Range
retrievedRanges = getRandomRanges
```

You can used `retrievedRanges` in different ways; for example:

```
   retrievedRanges(0).Value = "value I want to write in the A1 range"
```

Comment: @Simple_One No problem. The whole point of my answer is helping you to understand the ideas better such that you can fix the error you have now or, even better, create a function completely from scratch by your own, instead of copying existing codes.

Comment: Righto, got it working, thanks to your prompting, I was having a total brain fart there!

Apparently I can't post my corrected code for another 6 hours, I'll post it up once it lets me. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, edited the revised code into the original post, hopefully it helps someone else one day! :)

Comment: @Simple_One this is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but as far as I see you are trying to build an array of Ranges with the last cell of each Worksheet of a workbook.

My suggestion would be to create a temp array of ranges and populate it with the Range objects you want, and finally return this temp array. Now I see that previous answer of "varocarbas" just suggests the same idea

```
Function FindLastContentCell(Optional xlsWb As Workbook = Nothing, Optional xlsWs As Worksheet = Nothing) As Range()

    Dim myLastRow As Long, myLastCol As Long
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lastCell As Range
    Dim arrayTmp() As Range
    Dim index As Integer

    [Bunch of extra code removed]

    If xlsWb Is Nothing then
        Set xlsWb = ActiveWorkbook
    End if
    Redim arrayTemp (wks.Worksheets.Count) As Range
    For Each wks in xlsWb.Worksheets
        myLastRow = wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        myLastColumn = wks.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Set lastCell = wks.Cells(myLastRow,myLastColumn)
        Set arrayTemp(index) = lastCell
        index = index + 1
    Next
    Set FindLastContentCell = arrayTemp

End Function
```

Comment: yep, that's what I ended up doing (after come prodding from Varocarbas to get my brain moving again). Thanks also for your response though, it was spot on and you interpreted my original post exactly as I intended it, thanks!