# Is there a way to make this less hacky / work properly?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that checks the rows underneath the current one depending on the unique ID. There can be up to 6 unique ideas under the current record (loop variable = i) that match the current record being checked in the loop. After this is done, the records underneath are checked for specific conditions (loop variable x). However, for some reason, I'm running into several issues. The first is that I had to set the range references inside of both loops, otherwise I got an error. The second is that, all of the stuff after the x loop seems to be outputting in the i loop that came before it. What am I doing wrong, and how can i make this function properly?

Please find my code below:

```
Function First_check()
dim i as long, x as long
Dim numComponents As Variant
Dim in1 As Range, in2 As Range, in3 As Range, in4 As Range, in5 As Range, _
in6 As Range, in7 As Range, in8 As Range, in9 As Range, in10 As Range, _
in11 As Range, in12 As Range, in13 As Range, in14 As Range, in15 As Range, _
in16 As Range, in17 As Range, in18 As Range, in19 As Range, in20 As Range
Dim out1 As Range, out2 As Range, out3 As Range, out4 As Range, out5 As Range, _
out6 As Range, out7 As Range, out8 As Range, out9 As Range, out10 As Range, _
out11 As Range, out12 As Range, out13 As Range, out14 As Range, out15 As Range, _
out16 As Range, out17 As Range, out18 As Range, out19 As Range, out20 As Range
Dim str, msg, oft, BTG, LOB, pdf, mht, emails, zip_rar, xls, doc, xls_doc, mrTT, lobVal, cmt1, giveURL, giveURLm As String

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 2 To lastRow
 If Cells(i, 5).Value2 = Cells(i + 6, 5).Value2 Then 
     numComponents = 6
 ElseIf Cells(i, 5).Value2 = Cells(i + 5, 5).Value2 Then
     numComponents = 5
 ElseIf Cells(i, 5).Value2 = Cells(i + 4, 5).Value2 Then
     numComponents = 4
 ElseIf Cells(i, 5).Value2 = Cells(i + 3, 5).Value2 Then
     numComponents = 3
 ElseIf Cells(i, 5).Value2 = Cells(i + 2, 5).Value2 Then
     numComponents = 2
 ElseIf Cells(i, 5).Value2 = Cells(i + 1, 5).Value2 Then
     numComponents = 1
 Else
     numComponents = 0
 End If

 For x = i + 1 To i + numComponents

    Set in1 = Cells(i, 11) 'test
    Set in2 = Cells(i, 12) 
    Set in3 = Cells(i, 13) 
    Set in4 = Cells(i, 16) 'e
    Set in5 = Cells(i, 37) 'target date 
    Set in6 = Cells(i, 38) 'target date end
    Set in7 = Cells(i, 35) 'target date actual 
    Set in8 = Cells(i, 37) 'target date start
    Set in9 = Cells(i, 38) 'target date end
    Set in10 = Cells(x, 50) ' date start
    Set in11 = Cells(x, 51) ' date end
    Set in12 = Cells(i, 42) 'pro
    Set in13 = Cells(i, 43) 'reco
    Set in14 = Cells(x, 62) 'cert
    Set in15 = Cells(x, 63) 'com
    Set in16 = Cells(x, 64) 'comp
    Set in17 = Cells(x, 49) 'uniqueID
    'outs
    Set out1 = Cells(i, 72) 'test
    Set out2 = Cells(i, 73) '
    Set out3 = Cells(i, 74) '
    Set out4 = Cells(i, 75) 'e
    Set out5 = Cells(i, 76) 'tar
    Set out6 = Cells(i, 77) 'comp
    Set out7 = Cells(i, 78) 'pro
    Set out8 = Cells(i, 75) 'empty
    Set out9 = Cells(i, 80) 'cer
    Set out10 = Cells(i, 81) 'comp
    Set out11 = Cells(i, 85) 'pre
    Set out12 = Cells(i, 88) 'missing
    Set out13 = Cells(i, 89) 'missing2
    Set out14 = Cells(i, 71) 'uniqueID
    '------ATTACHMENT SET
    str = Cells(i, 46).Value2
    msg = UBound(Split(str, ".msg"))
    oft = UBound(Split(str, ".oft"))
    BTG = UBound(Split(str, "BTG"))
    LOB = UBound(Split(str, "LOB"))
    pdf = UBound(Split(str, ".pdf"))
    mht = UBound(Split(str, ".mht"))
    emails = msg + oft + pdf + mht
    zip_rar = UBound(Split(str, ".zip"))
    xls = UBound(Split(str, ".xls"))
    doc = UBound(Split(str, ".doc"))
    xls_doc = xls Or doc

    If (in8.Value2 <> in10.Value2) Or (in9.Value <> in11.Value2) Then 'date
        out6.Value2 = Cells(x, 49).Value2 & ", " & out6.Value2
    End If

    If IsBlank(in14.Value2) Then 'Check cer
        out9.Value2 = Cells(x, 49).Value2 & ", " & out9.Value2
    End If

    If IsBlank(in15.Value2) Or IsBlank(in16.Value2) Then 'check loc
        out10.Value2 = Cells(x, 49).Value2 & ", " & out10.Value2
    End If

    If Not IsBlank(in17.Value2) Then
        out14.Value2 = in17.Value2 & ", " & out14.Value2
    End If

Next x

If Not IsBlank(out6.Value2) Then 'date
    out6.Value2 = "Wrong dates"
    out6.Value2 = fixtrail(out6.Value2)
End If

 If Not IsBlank(out9.Value2) Then 'cert
    out9.Value2 = "Cert Issue"
    out9.Value2 = fixtrail(out9.Value2)
 End If

 If Not IsBlank(out10.Value2) Then 'comp
    out10.Value2 = "Comp not found"
    out10.Value2 = fixtrail(out10.Value2)
 End If

 If IsBlank(in1.Value2) Then
    out1.Value2 = "Missing type"
 End If


'
'many more checks happening that i omittied for brevity
'


  If numComponents = 0 Then
    Cells(i, 70).Value2 = "0"
Else
    Cells(i, 70).Value2 = numComponents
End If


 i = i + numComponents

Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Also, this really belongs on the code review stack exchange site. I tend to prefer **not** closing/migrating these questions, but you should be aware it is a better option for your question the next time you have working code you want to shorten, improve, or review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first idea that came to mind is using an array of `Range` objects to clean up the variable declarations:

```
Dim inRange(20) As Range
Dim outRange(20) As Range

'...

For x = i + 1 To i + numComponents
    Set inRange(1) = Cells(i, 11)
    Set inRange(2) = Cells(i, 12)
    '...
Next
```

This will work especially well if you can get a formula for the cell numbers that map to each array position.

Additionally, we can improve variables around how the two loops are nested. The outer loop uses the `i` variable, while the inner loop uses the `x` variable. Since these are both looking at rows, I would re-name them as `r0` and `r1` (or `rBase` and `rNested`, `rParent` and `rChild`, `rMaster` and `rDetail`, etc) to help you understand what you're looking at with each index. I also see that some of the Range objects depend on the current `i` value, while other depend on `x`. You should be able to assign the `i` ranges above the inner loop, and save some CPU/memory work that way:

```
For irParent = 2 To LastRow

    '...

    Set inRange(1) = Cells(irParent, 11) 'test
    Set inRange(2) = Cells(irParent, 12) 
    Set inRange(3) = Cells(irParent, 13) 
    Set inRange(4) = Cells(irParent, 16) 'e
    '...

    'If numComponents is 0, there are no child rows and this loop is skipped
    For rChild = rParent + 1 To rParent + numComponents
        Set inRange(10) = Cells(irChild, 50) ' date start
        Set inRange(11) = Cells(irChild, 51) ' date end

        '...

        str = Cells(irParent, 46).Value2
        msg = UBound(Split(str, ".msg"))
        oft = UBound(Split(str, ".oft"))
        '...

    Next

    irParent = irParent + numComponents
Next
```

Another thing is this method runs kind of long. You may want to abstract out some of the checks to a separate method, or a few separate methods that depend on what type of parent record you're looking at. Create methods that just accept the values needed for checking a particular kind of row, and then returns a single result for the check. This adds *names* to the code that help you understand what you're doing, as well as shorting the parent code to make it easier to read and understand at a high level more quickly.

As you make those other changes, you may want to start thinking in terms of creating Range objects that represent an entire row (or section from a row), so you can pass them to methods. This is especially true, as it appears many Range objects are currently used to hold values from single Cells. You can build strings to define non-contiguous Ranges that have the values needed for each row (including the parent cells when working in a child row). This will make building functions much easier, if you can have them simply accept a single Range object that you know has the correct cells in it.

This is also helpful because it minimizes instances where you copy from Excel Cells to memory. Moving data between VBA and Excel is a costly operation. It's usually better for performance to copy to or from a set of Cells in bulk, rather than one Cell at a time. This often holds even when it means using some extra memory. It also often helps reduce or simplify the total amount of code needed. Unfortunately, I'm too far out of VBA to show you an example.

Finally, notice my indentation. Professionals will do that consistently... even religiously. "Hacky" code does not. It's extremely helpful for spotting mistakes.

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for all the help. I will certainly make the loops more explicitly named, and try to condense the amount of checks being done per module. However, I have an issue with your array range -- VBA does not seem to accept 'dim in(20) as range'

Comment: @Gurrito It's been a while since I've done VBA. This may help with the Range array issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630704/using-an-array-of-ranges-in-vba-excel Basically, use a Range to hold a Range, rather than one cell, or copy the cell values from a Range into an array in one operation, and then copy them back later (transferring between Excel and memory is expensive). Also the `r` prefix in VBA usually means "Range". A better prefix for a row index is `ri` or `ir` (The latter so "i" for integer leads off). I'm updating my code now to use that.

Comment: Also... you can have non-contiguous ranges. Iterating through rows one at a time is okay, but it may be a good idea to build one-row Range strings for your values in each row (https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/629835-vba-array-ranges.html)